# Executing shell script which contains a while loop from Java

Tags: java, shell, process

I am having a critical trouble to execute a shell script which contains a while loop. Here is my shell script:

```
echo Here 1
sleep 0.05
echo Here 2
sleep 0.05
echo Here 3

ic=70
while [ $ic -ge 40 ]
do
        #sleep 0.05
        ic=$[$ic-1]
        echo Here $ic
done
```

When I am executing the script normally from the terminal as `/home/pi/tbe/testSleep.sh` it is working. and printing all the `echo`s.

Now I have written this java method to execute the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {       
    String command = "/home/pi/tbe/testSleep.sh";
    System.out.println("Executing command: " + command);

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    process.waitFor();
    int exitValue = process.exitValue();
    System.out.println("Command executed. Exit value: " + exitValue);
    process.destroy();  
}
```

And when I am executing it I can only see the following output:

```
Executing command: /home/pi/tbe/testSleep.sh
Here 1
Here 2
Here 3
Here $[70-1]
Command executed. Exit value: 0
```

This is really weird. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Specify the shell you want to use for the shell script. String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "/home/pi/tbe/testSleep.sh"}; Or add shebang in the script itself - #!/bin/bash (as first line).

Comment: You are testing your script using `bash`.  When called from the java process, the script is invoked using `sh`.  The script makes use of features not supported in `sh`, hence the difference in behavior.

Comment: It seems that the script is not properly interpreted, as it isn't run by the shell. Have you tried to add #!/bin/bash?

Comment: Thank you everybody. The issue is the shebang. I didn't added the #!/bin/bash through I created my process builder as @amit_g suggested. If you can post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the shell executing the command is not same as that you are using to run the script on command line. Specify the shell as bash.

Add shebang in the script (as first line). It is always a good practice to be specific about the shell in the script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You could also specify the shell you want to use for the shell script

```
String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "/home/pi/tbe/testSleep.sh"};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your script in Ubuntu:

```
$ sh script.sh
Here 1
Here 2
Here 3
Here $[70-1]
script.sh: 8: [: Illegal number: $[70-1]
```

Apparently $[70-1] is not being evaluated but simply treated as a literal...

I saw the comments after I saved. They are correct. Using bash (I was lazy) gives the correct results.